# Android manager not giving notification after 5 sec

Tags: android

I am trying to use alarm manager to show notification after 5 sec. I have tried many sites but was not able to understand please give a simple example for explaining how to use alarm manager and connect notification with it.

I am newbie.

this is function i used to set alarm and I am not getting notification after 5 secs not in emulator nor in android mobile.

```
public void setAlarm(View view)
{

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReciver.class);

    Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

tv.setText("completed");
}
```

and this class to make it work

```
public class AlertReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    createNotification(context,"times Up", "5 SEcond has passed", "Alert");

}

public void createNotification(Context context,String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert){

    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ne)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);

    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

Comment: Meaning i have android 4.2.2 meaning api 19 so it wont wakeup so i shall use 16 or lower but still i had issue i usesed eclair also 2.2.1

Comment: I tried puttint setExact it is still not working sry. I need a more clear explaning please i just increased my min api to 19 too.